# Can't send data from a obj-c client to a java server

Tags: java, objective-c, client

I'm writing an iPhone app that deals with a server side and a client side. The problem I'm having is that I'm not able to send any data from my app (Client side) to my java program (Server side). I'm kind of stuck right now, and any help would be much appreciated.

My obj-c code (Client):

```
- (BOOL) initConnection: (NSString *) ipAddr {
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)ipAddr, 4444, NULL, &writeStream);

if(!writeStream)
    return NO;

outStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *) writeStream;

[outStream setDelegate:self];

[outStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[outStream open];

self.data = [[NSData alloc] init];

return YES;


- (void) sendCommand: (NSString *) command {
NSLog(@"Command that was sent to method: %@", command);

self.data = [NSData dataWithBytes:@"This is a test\n" length:16];

int bytes = [outStream write:[self.data bytes] maxLength:[self.data length]];
```

My Java code (Server):

```
private void handleCommands() {
    try {
        do {
            System.out.println("Right before reading socket");
            msg = in.readLine();

            System.out.println("Received: " + msg);

        } while(!EOC);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What happens is that when I send data from my app the code on my server side never gets past
**msg = in.readLine()**. When I terminate the connection on the app side it prints out that the string received was **null**.

Answer (score 1):

Actually on this line of code:

```
self.data = [NSData dataWithBytes:@"This is a test\n" length:16];
```

the string length is 15, but you're passing 16 as parameter. Maybe it's waiting for the last char?

Try not hard-coding the string length, something like:

```
NSString *msgStr = @"This is a test\n";
self.data = [NSData dataWithBytes:msgStr length:[msgStr length]];
```